# Why does Notes only show a sub-set of the Share extensions enabled on my Mac?

Tags: sharing, notes.app, plugins

[image: My Share menu in Safari]

I'm really enjoying the new version of Notes.app, now that I can set the text size to something I can read. But one aspect continues to bug me, and maybe it's some setting I haven't found. The first image above shows the list of apps in my Share menu, as listed in Safari, but in Notes it is a smaller list.

[image: Share menu in Notes]

I would like the 'Add to Together' share item to be available to me in Notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to the individual share extension developer to tell the system which inputs are compatible with their extension, and to then implement the necessary code to be compatible with each.

Comment: Thanks ... so I should ask the developer of Together this question?